# Python Unit Testing Mock incorrectly

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am new to unit testing in Python. I trying to write unit tests for my class. However I am running into issues:

```
from <path1> import InnerObj
from <path2> import new_obj
from <path3> import XYZ

class ClassToBeTested(object):

def __init__(self):
    obj = new_obj(param1 = "XYZ", time = 1, innerObj = InnerObj())
    self.attr1 = XYZ(obj)


 def method(self, random, paramStr):

 // Remainder of class
```

Test class:

```
from mock import patch, PropertyMock, MagicMock
from <path1> import InnerObj
from <path2> import new_obj
from <path3> import XYZ


@pytest.fixture()
@patch('<path1>.InnerObj', new=MagicMock())
@patch('<path2>.new_obj', new=MagicMock())
@patch('<path3>.XYZ', new=MagicMock())
def mock_test():
    return ClassToBeTested()

def test_method_true(mock_test):
     random = Random_Object()

     booleanResult = mock_test.method(random, paramStr)
     assert booleanResult == True
```

The error I get is `ERROR at setup of test_method_true ______`

The error stack mentions
    innerObj/**init**.py:26: in **init**
        qwerty_main = qwerty_assistant.get_root()

I am likely to believe that mocking is not done correctly for InnerObj as it should not be invoking the code in the init method of mocked objects.

Am I doing something wrong here? Can someone please help in pointing to right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patch` should target the import that is being used and not the path to the import.

For example

`@patch('<path1>.InnerObj', new=MagicMock())`

`<path1>` is the location to the definition of `InnerObj` and not the file using it.  To address this, the `InnerObj` import should be patched in the module that imports `InnerObj`

Pretend that the path to `ClassToBeTested` is `path.to.class.to.be.tested`

The patch would be:

`@patch('path.to.class.to.be.tested.InnerObj', new=MagicMock())`

Comment: I believe thats what I am doing. value of <path1> is the same that is used in the `import statements` in the test class as well as original code. The same value of <path1> is patched as well

Comment: It should NOT be the path used in the import statement , it should be the path to the class which is importing it, in this case the file that contains Classtobetested